# Alternate way to do this without a LinkedList?

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, linked-list

My IDE suggested I use a LinkedList, so it automatically imported it into my code. But is there a way to achieve the same thing but without importing a LinkedList and using only an ArrayList? Apparently its possible but I have no idea how.

```
/**
 * Search this Twitter for the latest Tweet of a given author.
 * If there are no tweets from the given author, then the
 * method returns null.
 * O(1)
 */
public Tweet latestTweetByAuthor(String author) {
    //getting hashvalue for the date
    int hashValue = tweetsByAuthor2.hashFunction(author);

    //getting all the hashtable buckets
    ArrayList<LinkedList<HashPair<String, Tweet>>> allBuckets = tweetsByAuthor2.getBuckets();

    //if buckets at hashvalue == null
    if (allBuckets.get(hashValue) == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return allBuckets.get(hashValue).get(allBuckets.get(hashValue).size() - 1).getValue();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
   public Tweet latestTweetByAuthor(String author) {
        // getting hashvalue for the date
        int hashValue = tweetsByAuthor2.hashFunction(author);

        // getting all the hashtable buckets
        ArrayList<ArrayList<HashPair<String, Tweet>>> allBuckets = tweetsByAuthor2.getBuckets();

        // if buckets at hashvalue == null
        if (allBuckets.get(hashValue) == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return allBuckets.get(hashValue).get(allBuckets.get(hashValue).size() - 1).getValue();
        }
    }
```

Comment: So the implementation of `getBuckets()` returns `ArrayList<LinkedList`?

Comment: yes, in another class i have

    private ArrayList<LinkedList<HashPair<K, V>>> buckets;

Answer (score 1):

You can, but you have to change your `tweetsByAuthor2.getBuckets()` return type as well to `ArrayList<ArrayList<HashPair<String, Tweet>>> getBuckets()`. 
Other than that you don't use any specific functionality of `LinkedList`. Only here `allBuckets.get(hashValue).get(allBuckets.get(hashValue).size() - 1)` I see that you use `LinkedList.get()`. ArrayList has the same method as well.

Also, general advise, if possible use Interfaces, not Implementations. So your `tweetsByAuthor2.getBuckets()` will look like this then: `List<List<HashPair<String, Tweet>>> getBuckets()`. This way you don't even have to care what implementation is used.

For example, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/932467/4686871) stackoverflow answer for advantages of using interfaces as a return type

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 10 or later versions you can use [var](https://developer.oracle.com/java/jdk-10-local-variable-type-inference.html) keyword for complex variable types for sake of clarity.

```
/**
 * Search this Twitter for the latest Tweet of a given author.
 * If there are no tweets from the given author, then the
 * method returns null.
 * O(1)
 */
public Tweet latestTweetByAuthor(String author) {
    //getting hashvalue for the date
    int hashValue = tweetsByAuthor2.hashFunction(author);

    //getting all the hashtable buckets
    var allBuckets = tweetsByAuthor2.getBuckets();

    //if buckets at hashvalue == null
    if (allBuckets.get(hashValue) == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return allBuckets.get(hashValue).get(allBuckets.get(hashValue).size() - 1).getValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: using var worked and I can get rid of my linkedList import from my java file. Can you please explain why this works?

Comment: var is a pretty nice little addition to the Java language in terms of productivity and readability you can read more from here: https://developer.oracle.com/java/jdk-10-local-variable-type-inference.html